# Problems with event listener that has previously worked in other code

Tags: javascript, html, event-listener

**Please note**
** I have added in my other function to see if it can make the issue clearer.
My code works perfectly in the 'code snippet' section, however, my actual program will not run. Maybe I should add- I have another method in my external js file, would this have anything to do with the event listeners not working?

**What I want my program to do**
When a user chooses what item they wish to purchase and the total amount of them they want the total cost will be updated.

**What I have tried**
I have added an event listener after my function in an external Javascript file. I have previously used this code in another programme, and it worked perfectly, however it was internal javascript.
I've tried changing the placement of where I have linked the js file from the head section to the body, but it still doesn't work. I've also tried moving the event listener statement to inside the function and before it and still no luck. Any advice would be hugely appreciated.

**My code**

```js
   
function validate(){
  var x = document.getElementById("name").value;
  var y = document.getElementById("email").value;
  var z = document.getElementById("phoneNumber").value;

  if (x == ""){
    alert("Please provide a name");
    return false
 }

  if (y == ""){
    alert("Please provide an email address");
    return false
 }

 if (z == ""){
    alert("Please provide a phone number");
    return false
  }
}

function totalCost() {
  var dive = document.getElementById("diveChoice").value;
  var amount = document.getElementById("quantity").value;

  if (dive === "cenote") {
    document.getElementById("total").value =
      amount * 150;
  }

  if (dive === "shark") {
    document.getElementById("total").value =
      amount * 200;
  }

  if (dive === "reef") {
    document.getElementById("total").value =
      amount * 100;
  }
}
document.getElementById('diveChoice').addEventListener('change', totalCost);
document.getElementById('quantity').addEventListener('change', totalCost);
```

```html
<form name = "myForm" onsubmit = "return validate()" method="post">
<table>

    <tr>
      <td><label for="name">Name:</label><br></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="name" name="name"  /><br></td>

      </tr>

      <tr>

      <td><label for="email">Email address: </label><br></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="email" /></td><br>

      </tr>

      <tr>
      <td> <label for="phoneNumber">Phone number: </label><br></td>
      <td><input type="number" id="phoneNumber" name="phoneNumber" /> 
       </td><br>
      </tr>


<tr>
  <td><label for="diveChoice">Please select which dive you would like to purchase: 
            </label></td>
  <td>
    <select id="diveChoice">
      <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected"> Select option</option>
      <option value="cenote">Cenote Dive</option>
      <option value="shark">Dive with Bull Sharks</option>
      <option value="reef">Reef Dive</option>
  </td>
  </select>
  </td>
</tr>

<!-- number input to get amount of dives required -->
<tr>
  <td> <label for="quantity"> How many people are coming to on the dive? </label> </td>
  <td> <input type="number" id="quantity" name="quantity" min=1></td><br>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><label> Total cost: </label></td>
  <td><input type="text" id="total" /><br></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><input type= "submit" value ="Submit" /> </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: The code works OK when run using the "Run code snippet" button above (Google Chrome, Latest Version).  What's the best way to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Weird, the code snippet works for me aswell.. just not when I actually run my project. I also have another function in my external js file, would that cause any issues with how I have declared the event listeners?

Comment: "I've also tried moving the event listener statement to inside the function" This will break it, cart-before-horse scenario.   Moving it before is technically OK but frowned upon for reliability.

Comment: "I have another method in my external js file, would this have anything to do with the event listeners not working?" It definitely could.  If the script errors out, it can break execution thereafter for that one script.

Comment: I've updated the code in the post with the other function, which comes before the function that I'm trying to get to work now. If you get the chance could you have a look at it please? Thanks so much for your replies!

Comment: The code still seems to work here, but when I run it normally, it still doesn't

Comment: It's still working for me too (unfortunately).  I've posted an answer which explains how to handle a potential race condition with loading external JavaScript files, as well as answers to the rest of the questions.

Comment: If you run the code in the browser console directly after the page is fully loaded. Does it work? If it does, then it's the external js or somethings else is the problem

Comment: @AnthonyC no still doesn't work, do I need to have any tags or anything linked to my html file? I just have my css file and java file linked?

Comment: Spitballing here, but are there any other details that could be left out such as a legacy `DOCTYPE` declaration?

Comment: I don't know if this would make any difference, in html, where I get the users option is inside a form, the form runs the validate function when submit is selected, would this be causing any issues? @tresf

Comment: You ran the code directly in the console and it still doesn't work? Did it show any error?

Comment: @AnthonyC all that came up was: Error: Could not find or load main class book

Comment: Isn't that a JAVA error?

Comment: "where I get the users option is inside a form, the form runs the validate function when submit is selected, would this be causing any issues?"  Unfortunately, the validate function above doesn't have the corresponding HTML.   For example, `document.getElementById("name")` is called above but an element with an id of "name" doesn't exist in the above example.

Comment: @AnthonyC yep haha that's what I thought too, but my file is definitely a .js one.. I dunno what's going on

Comment: I updated with the rest of the HTML code, and it's still working here, but not when I run it.. So strange

Comment: The rest of my code works fine for the validation, but when I try the part for the dive the user wants it will not work at all

Answer (score -1):

Placing the various questions into a single answer:

> I have another method in my external js file, would this have anything to do with the event listeners not working?

It definitely could. If the script errors out, it can break execution thereafter for that one script.

> I've tried changing the placement of where I have linked the js file from the head section to the body, but it still doesn't work

External files can load before the page is done rendering, so [adding a document listener](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp) is a good way to make sure you're not running into any timing issues.

> I've also tried moving the event listener statement to inside the function

This will break it, cart-before-horse scenario.

> I've also tried moving the event listener [...] before it and still no luck.

Moving it before is technically OK but frowned upon for readiblity.